# How to create a multi-core Android virtual device

Tags: android-emulator, android-virtual-device

Is there a way to create an Android Virtual Device with more than one CPU core?

I'm using the Android Virtual Device Manager Rev 19 on Windows 7 AMD64.

Please note that this question is *not* about getting the emulator to use multiple host cores!